# Replacing an entry in a list (sentence.replace())

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a text based adventure game.  still in early stages of development, and I'm having a lot of problems with equating a given sentence to directional and or action commands.  here is a snippet of what I have so far. will get the error "list object has no attribute replace":

```
sentence_parsing = input().split(" ")

travel = ["Move", "move", "MOVE", "Go", "go", "GO", "Travel", "travel", "TRAVEL"]
command_length = len(sentence_parsing)
for command in range(command_length):
    for action in range(9):
        if travel[action] == sentence_parsing[command]:
            sentence_parsing = sentence_parsing.replace(travel[action], "1")
```

after applying values to known key words, I need to remove all unknown words, which I think I can do with a similar set of nested loops checking if the original sentence and the modified have matching words then remove if they do. after that I need to make the string number values in the list become integers and multiply them together.  I do have alternative logic built in to correct negation in sentences, but it works perfectly.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use `sentence_parsing.lower()` to reduce your `travel` to three elements.

Comment: also instead of two loops, you can test if the command is in the list `travel` using the `in` operator: `for command in sentence_parsing: if command.lower() in travel: do_stuff()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating through `travel`, you might want to iterate through the words in `sentence_parsing` instead.

```py
# Make sure that your parser is not case-sensitive by transforming 
# all words to lower-case:
sentence_parsing = [x.lower() for x in input().split(" ")]

# Create a dictionary with your command codes as keys, and lists of 
# recognized command strings as values. Here, the dictionary contains
# not only ``travel'' commands, but also ``eat'' commands:
commands = {
    "1": ["move", "go", "travel"],
    "2": ["consume", "gobble", "eat"]}

# Iterate through the words in sentence_parsing. 
# ``i'' contains the index in the list, ``word'' contains the actual word:
for i, word in enumerate(sentence_parsing):
    # for each word, go through the keys of the command dictionary:
    for code in commands:
         # check if the word is contained in the list of commands 
         # with this code: 
         if word in commands[code]:
             # if so, replace the word by the command code:
             sentence_parsing[i] = code
```

With the input string

> Go north. Eat fruit. Travel east. Consume goblin.

the list `sentence_parsing` looks like this after execution of the code:

```
['1', 'north.', '2', 'fruit.', '1', 'east.', '2', 'goblin.']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input().split()
```

leaves you with a list of strings.  You can examine them one at a time with a `for` loop.

```
for command in sentence_parsing:
    if command in travel:
        #do something
    else:
        #do a different thing
```

If you're looking to only keep words you recognize from travel, you can do:

```
sentence_parsing = [command for command in sentence_parsing if command in travel]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
travel[action] = "1"
```

but i think you must use the dict, or assign value to specific number in list. For example:

```
>>>list = [0, 0]
>>>list
[0, 0]
>>>list[1] = "1"
>>>list
[0, '1']
```

P.S You must apply `.replace()` to strings in list, not the full list. Like this : `travel[0].replace()`